# Cannot configure xdebug; "Operation not permitted" error when trying to cp

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, permission

I'm trying to configure xdebug, but when I run the command

`cp Downloads/xdebug-2.6.1/xdebug-2.6.1/modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303`

I get a "Operation not permitted" warning from the terminal, even when I use `sudo`

I checked the security and privacy settings to make sure the terminal had full disk access and made sure the files in question were unlocked.

What else could be prompting this error?

Comment: `/usr/lib` is protected by SIP, user-supplied libraries should be installed in `/usr/local/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to temporarily disable System Integrity Protection

https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/